# Grouping by the results of a subquery - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

long-time user, first time poster.

This is a question about using the results of a subquery to aggregate a count.  I am completely open to changing my approach, but wanted to be sure there wasn't something easy I was missing first.

Say I have a table of Orders that has these columns:

```
Order_Id
Order_Datetime
Order_Type
Order_Status
```

and I've created an indexed view to support the most used read access:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersByDate WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121) AS Order_Date,
       Order_Type,
       Order_Status,
       COUNT_BIG(*)
  FROM Orders
 GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121), Order_Type, Order_Status;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vw_OrdersByDate_main_idx ON
       (Order_Date, Order_Type, Order_Status);
```

So far, so good.  And when reading for reporting (with (noexpand)) it performs blinding quickly across ~50M Orders.  However, now we've come out with an industry-changing product, that every executive needs to know, on a second-by-second basis, how the product is moving.

We have a child table of OrderLines that has the following columns:

```
OrderLine_Id
Order_Id
Product_Id
```

Here's lies the problem, I would 'like' to add a column to my original view such that I can filter by Orders that contain the super-product and those that don't.  Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersByDate WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121) AS Order_Date,
       Order_Type,
       Order_Status,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderLines OL 
                          WHERE OL.Order_Id = O.Order_Id 
                            AND Product_Id = 123) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS Super_Product_Exists,
       COUNT_BIG(*)
  FROM Orders O
 GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121), Order_Type,
          Order_Status, Super_Product_Exists;
```

But I can't do that.  I've tried putting the entire CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause and "cannot use an aggregate or a subquery... for the group by list...".  I can't use a LEFT JOIN / NULL because you can't create an index on a view with any sort of outer join.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but can't figure it out (and neither could the Google...  at least within my search skills).

Any help would be extremely appreciated, and like I said before, I am open to entirely different strategies, though I don't have a lot of latitude to change the existing transactional data structures...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to your EXISTS with the columns you have in your outer query, which means you have to expose those columns in your EXISTS:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121) AS Order_Date,
       Order_Type,
       Order_Status,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderLines OL 
                         INNER JOIN Orders OLO                 
                          ON OL.Order_Id = OLO.Order_Id 
                         WHERE OLO.OrderType=O.OrderType
                         AND OLO.Order_Status=O.Order_Status
                            AND OL.Product_Id = 123) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS Super_Product_Exists,
       COUNT_BIG(*)
  FROM Orders O
 GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Datetime, 121), Order_Type,
          Order_Status;
```

Comment: Just a minor remark: there doesn't seem to be `OrderType` or `Order_Status` in the table `OrderLines ` (as far as I can see).

Comment: No, those columns are in Orders, which is why I joined to Orders in the EXISTS query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tab.  That is something that I had not considered, and when I change it to a COUNT instead of an EXISTS, it gives me exactly what I want (count of orders containing SuperProducts within the timeframe, by order type and status).  I also had to join the Order_Date to get the right count within the timeframe, which is not pretty (but necessary).  That said, evidentially you cant create a index on a view with a subselect either, so I'm going to need to figure something else out.

Comment: Maybe you can change the subselect to an outer join and count the non-nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to see all products and highlight superproducts, I added a calculated field based on product_id = 123 named superproduct with values yes or no.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),Orders.Order_datetime, 121) AS Order_Date, 
Orders.order_type, 
Orders.order_status,
OrderLines.Product_id, 
CASE WHEN OrderLines.product_id =123 
     THEN 'Yes' 
     ELSE'No' 
END AS SuperProduct, 
COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountBig
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN OrderLines ON Orders.Order_id = OrderLines.Order_id
GROUP BY 
CONVERT(varchar(10), 
Orders.Order_datetime, 121), 
Orders.order_type, 
Orders.order_status, 
OrderLines.Product_id
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYUj5.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on the answer given. Pure code answers often tend to be quite hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the response DDD, I should have made it clear that the counts need to be distinct orders with SuperProducts and without, and that orders can each be for multiple products.  I believe this will double count a single order with both types of products.